# How to clear screen area or Redraw screen in C#

Tags: c#, gdi+

I am creating a User Control in C#.Net 2.0.
I have to apply drag and Drop Images in between these controls.
I have done drag and drop effect.

But the problem is that i have to show the control movement while mouse dragging.
For that i am drawing a rectangle on screen with the help of ControlDraw.DrawReversibleFrame()

Problem is that while drawing with mouse move event Rectangle is drawn over whole screen and because no repaint on screen it exist on screen.

So please can anybody tell me either how to clear drawn graphics or how to force to redraw screen.

Comment: Do you mean that when you drag something and move you mouse over the control (with the left-button down), you want to see a rectangle being shown on the control just below the mouse? That rectangle will move with the mouse until you drop the stuff over it?

Comment: I want to drag control itself and drop on Like Panel.
So for showing control is dragging i want to show a rectangle of same size as control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must draw the 'reversable' frame in the same position as previously to reverse it, before drawing the next frame in the new position.

The pseudo-code is:

```
bool prev_rev_frame = false;
Rect prev_rev_rect;

...

void on_mouse_move() {
  if(prev_rev_frame)
    Control.drawReversableFrame(prev_rev_rect);
  Rect new_rev_rect = ....
  Control.drawReversableFrame(new_rev_rect);
  prev_rev_frame = true;
  prev_rev_rect = new_rev_rect;
}
```

But in general, I **recommend** changing the mouse cursor to a drag-drop icon or a thumbnail of the image would be far more appropriate.

Comment: thanks Will,
ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame() - It draws a frame on screen with reverse color than its background.
Here i have no issue.

I can change the mouse cursor but is not my requirement.
Requirement is to show the user control is dragging.
thanks